# How to left outer join to from select grouped and summed into LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this select I need to convert to linq. I can do normal group bys with summing, but I can not wrap my head around doing the select within the from area.

```
SELECT a.soptype,
   a.sopnumbe,
   b.lnitmseq,
   b.itemnmbr,
   b.itemdesc,
   b.quantity - Isnull(GMCD.mcqty, 0) AS Balance,
   a.custnmbr,
   a.custname
FROM   sop10100 a
   JOIN sop10200 b
     ON a.soptype = b.soptype
        AND b.sopnumbe = a.sopnumbe
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT soptype,
                           sopnumbe,
                           lnitmseq,
                           Sum(quantity) AS mcqty
                    FROM   mcdetail
                    GROUP  BY soptype,
                              sopnumbe,
                              lnitmseq) AS GMCD
                ON GMCD.soptype = b.soptype
                   AND GMCD.sopnumbe = b.sopnumbe
                   AND GMCD.lnitmseq = b.lnitmseq
WHERE  voidstts = 0
   AND b.itemnmbr = 'TestItem'
   AND b.quantity - Isnull(GMCD.mcqty, 0) > 0
```

Comment: [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) could help you learn

Comment: since your inner select doesn't reference anything in the containing query, you can define the inner select separately as an `IQueryable` first... then in the main query, just left outer join to that `IQueryable` variable ... the left outer join syntax itself is found variously on this site and others ... eg [101 linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin)